# std::unique_lock<std::mutex> prohibit dll unloading

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have an issue while unloading a dll. It is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460809/c-dll-unloading-issue) one but quit different. I'm loading a dll using [LoadLibraryA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then call a function and close the dll with [FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, the dll is not unloaded but FreeLibrary return success.
reduced code:

```
void foo() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
}
```

While debugging the code and looking into [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) unique_lock creates a second thread, **but why**? Also this thread is running as long as the application runs. There is nothing else; no other handle to the dll, no other functions. Also the dll is still loaded in the program. If I remove the line above, everything is fine. The dll is unloaded fine, no extra threads. So my question is, **how to avoid this behavior and why is unique_lock creating a thread?**

The mutex is intended for multithreading, but while testing, there is only **one** thread, loading the dll calling foo, and unloading the dll.

### edit:

I don't know if this is a bug in the visual studio implementation of mutex/unique_lock but I solved the problem by using boost's mutex/unique_lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Visual Studio, they increase the reference count of the DLL abnormally when you use std::thread or std::mutex, etc.

See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781665/stl-using-std-threading-objects-adds-extra-load-count-for-hosted-dll#tabs) bug report.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this bug has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015.
See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fa38310-b976-4cb4-b54d-7f16e5feaba5/std-threading-calls-hanging-onto-dll-referance?forum=vcgeneral) for details.

> ... I can confirm that the issue is not occurring with VS2015. ...