# How can I wrap a function (std::bind) into a namespaces?

Tags: c++, bind, wrapper

I want to wrap the bind class template into an separate namespace:

```
namespace my_space {
template<typename... R> using bind = std::bind<R...>;
}
```

and get an error:

```
error: 'bind<R ...>' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.
```

How am i able to do so? A small example can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97055364dca672f9).

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Comment: could be to choose between `std::bind` and `boost::bind` and always include the desired one in your own namespace.

Comment: @user1810087 random gotcha: don't mix `boost::bind` with `std::function` and vice versa. there are some potential harmful specializations in library code!

Comment: @Alex, thank you for the hint. i already knew that, and wrap function and bind in the namespace (and some others). i use it to avoid [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703197/stdunique-lockstdmutex-prohibit-dll-unloading) bug...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why your code does not work

Your code doesn't compile because `std::bind` is a *function*, not a *type*. You can declare aliases using `using` only for types.

While `g++` diagnostic is not exactly the best, Clang++ would have [given you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c643db52430a0f99) the following error:

> error: expected a type

which is much clearer*.

#### What you can do

Thankfully you can just import the `std::bind` name using:

```
namespace my_space {
    using std::bind;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4649b0d585f08185)

This is specifically defined in:

> **§7.3.3/1** The `using` declaration [namespace.alias]
>
> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.

<sub>* Personal opinion.</sub>

Comment: How come "less verbose" means "much clearer"? The point of both messages is identical.

Comment: Clang and gcc diagnostic messages tell the same thing, but gcc is more verbose. I don't get how come less verbose clang's message appears much clearer to you.

Comment: @Ruslan Oh, no. I didn't mean that. GCC is actually [less verbose](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa0710d3a5c9ec0) than [Clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c643db52430a0f99), but while Clang++ identifies the problem correctly (with the message "expected a type"), GCC returns a cryptic error (maybe just for me): "'bind<R ...>' in namespace 'std' does not name a type" that almost suggests that you didn't include the correct headers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can get that to work with using, but an alternative might be wrapping via perfect-forwarding. Any good compiler would optimize the wrapper away.

```cpp
namespace my_space {
    template<class... Args>
    auto bind(Args&&... args) -> decltype( std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
    {
        return std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

In C++14 you can even drop the `-> decltype( std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )` part.

A working example can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e6dd47962319a2)

Answer (score 2):

If you're really keeping the template parameters as the original has them, then simply bring the name in:

```
namespace my_space {
  using std::bind;
}
```